# What are the published adventures for WFRP which are not set plots?

Tags: published-adventures, wfrp-2e, wfrp-4e, wfrp-1e, wfrp

Many of the published adventures for Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay(WFRP) follow a set plot and are a bit of a railroad experience, for example "Through the Drakwald" and "Ashes of Middenheim" for WFRP2.

One I know of that doesn't follow this pattern is "Spires of Altdorf" for WFRP2 which is much more open ended. The players are allowed to talk to whatever characters they want in whatever order and other than some assassination attempts, there aren't really scripted encounters.

What other published modules are there with an open sandbox experience?